# Mirth: calling an SSL SOAP web service with a client certificate

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, client-certificates, mirth

The scenario is around calling an external SSL SOAP web service from within Mirth. The web service is requires an SSL/TLS connection along with a client certificate.

The intention is to use the built-in SOAP Sender Destination to call the remote secure web service, and somehow include that client certificate.

I understand that you first need to install that client certificate into the Java runtime. This may be within the Java runtime's certificate store or the Jetty certstore.

The platform:

- Windows 2003 SP2
- Mirth 1.8
- Java jre1.5.0_09

**Question**: what configuration steps (Mirth, JRE certificate stores, etc.) would you suggest to successfully have a Mirth SOAP Sender include a client certificate (*.cer) when calling a web service secured by SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirth 1.8 cannot send a client cert when calling a SOAP web service.

Answer (score 3):

The Java runtime, or more specifically, the Sun JSSE provider, will present a client certificate if some system properties are set. You can read details in the [JSSE Reference Guide,](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization) but the important properties are `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`.

There are a few drawbacks to this approach. First, setting the key store password as a system property makes it accessible to any code running in that process—although this can be controlled if a `SecurityManager` is installed. Second, these settings will be used for any SSL sockets created through the "default" `SSLContext`. If you need different credentials for different endpoints, you'll need a Mirth-specific solution.

No starting point was specified in the question, but if starting from scratch, the easiest approach is to create a new Java Key Store ("JKS" format) and generate a new key pair and a CSR. After sending the CSR to the CA and getting a certificate back, import it into the same key store. That key store is ready to use.

If a certificate is already available, it is likely to be in a stored with its corresponding private key in PKCS #12 format (.p12 or .pfx file). These can be used directly by a Java application, but the `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` property will need to be set to `"PKCS12"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm late a bit here for this but actually there is a possibility that it could.  By sending a few config parameters to the JVM you could get the underlying SOAP engine to switch to HTTPs and provide the proper certificate.

refer to this question for details on which parameters to set for configuring the VM

[Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication)

you will notice there are quite a few things to take care of.  Normally HTTPs and client authentication should "just work" once you configured your certificates appropriately.  BUT there are some servers out there that are not so friendly to B2B style clients so you have to watch out.

Using JDK 6_21 and a few tweaks with the certificate I was able to get one of them servers to behave but it was long and painful on our side for something that takes about 15 minutes to configure properly on the server.

here is another question that address this very issue (client side authentication towards unfriendly servers).

[Client SSL authentication causing 403.7 error from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531712/client-ssl-authentication-causing-403-7-error-from-iis)