# java communicate over ssl

Tags: java, ssl

I have to write a java program that hits a url

> `https://localhost:8443/ping.jsp`

over ssl and returns the response whether the application is up or not. If I hit that url manually from my web browser it asks for security certificates and when I provide them it communicates with the application and displayes the response on the web page. I want to automate this process so that the java program takes care of providing the security certificates and everything. I could do it if it were not for ssl and security certificates but I am not sure how to automate this part (providing certificates).

I have truststore/keystore files but I am not sure how to use them in order to accomplish the task. Any ideas or any useful links that I should follow ?

Comment: Are you talking about use client certificates?

Comment: I think so but I am not sure. All I know is that when I hit that url manually, it asks for security cerficates, I select a certificate from my local hard disk and then it establishes the connection and displays the result of the ping. I've to automate this process so that a java program will do this process and provide the security certificate and displays the result of ping message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request a URL that requires a client certificate for authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734613/how-to-request-a-url-that-requires-a-client-certificate-for-authentication)