# Java - Using a certificate and private key to make an HTTP POST request

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, private-key

I am making an POST request in Java that requires an ssl certificate and private key combination. I have looked at Java KeyStore and create a .jks file from both the .key and .cert files using the two commands:

```
winpty openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey privatekey.key -out abc.p12
```

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore abc.jks -deststoretype JKS`

But this failed the request with a 403 exception. Effectively, I want to perform the following Javascript's functions in java:

```
function cardBalance(intent, session, response) {
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.crt'),
        host: "blah.blah.blah.com',
        path: '/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr/creditcardsummary',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + session.user.accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Version': '1.1.0',
            'zId': '1234',
            'aId': '123456789',
            'bId': 'bId',
            'AppName': 'AppName'
        }
    };

    var postData = JSON.stringify({
        'acctnum': '00002600452999820832'
    });

    console.log(options);

    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log('Request Credit Card Balance');
        var data = '';

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);

            if (data.CreditCardSummary.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                var balance = data.balance;
                console.log('Balance: ' + balance);
                var speechOutput = 'The current balance is $' + balance;
                response.tell(speechOutput);
            } else {
                response.tell('There was a problem getting your card balance.');
            }

        });
    });

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('An Error Occurred when calling the Gateway. ' + e);
        response.tell(e);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve], a specific error, and what you've tried to solve it so far.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough detail. thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out and I wanted to provide reference for other people. I had to convert my .key and .crt files to .p12 file and then convert that to a .jks file.
I did that by following this link here [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i) 
Once I had my keystore properly set up I followed this page in java [How to request a URL that requires a client certificate for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734613/how-to-request-a-url-that-requires-a-client-certificate-for-authentication). Where I went wrong is that I did not correctly set my JVM arguments. I had to put these   **javax.net.ssl.keyStore** and 
**javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword**. Once I added that to my JVM it ran perfectly.