# Need suggestion for passing certificate information in HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, httpsurlconnection

I have the server running which listens on HTTPs protocol. This server is running on tomcat 9. I have the certificate file on local and also have the password for it. I am trying to hit a URL of this server with HttpsURLConnection class. How can I pass certificate information to get successfully connected to the server?

I am able to successfully connect to the server if the server runs on HTTP protocol with HttpURLConnection. But with the secured connection I got "java.security.cert.CertificateException"  and "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException" exception.

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate? Two you need to do two way SSL Handshake? Meaning client must be recognized by server?

Comment: Yes. I am using self signed certificate. I have tried from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734613/how-to-request-a-url-that-requires-a-client-certificate-for-authentication. But still error came.