# java security problem the page requires a client certificate

Tags: java, certificate, axis, security, webservice-client

I have a certificate. pfx to access a webservice.

I followed the steps listed on [this page](http://unbeagleyyo.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/firmar-webservices-axis-con-wss4j-y-certificados-x509/#comment-38)

When looking at the xml sent is encrypted.

But the server returns me the message:

```
The page requires a client certificate
.........
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
.......
Server Microsoft-IIS/6.0
```

I can see the definition of this server from the browser if I have this certificate installed (the certificate is correct).

Also I have to use username and password to see the definition of service.

In the Trustor I have the server certificate.

I'm programming in java and use axis, any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Axis client to inclue a client certificate with your outgoing request. This is different from server certificates which are more common. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication) gives good info on setting up client certs in Java:

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
System.setProperty(“javax.net.ssl.keyStore”, “path/keystore.jks”);
System.setProperty(“javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword”, “pass”);
System.setProperty(“javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType”, “PKCS12″);
System.setProperty(“javax.net.ssl.trustStore”, “path/trusstore.jks”);
System.setProperty(“javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword”, “pass”);
System.setProperty(“com.sun.net.ssl.dhKeyExchangeFix”, “true”);
```