# How to HIGHLY restrict users with "specific roles" to access the application from "a certain place"?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I need to restrict specific user's roles to use the application while are accessing it from a specific place lets say "Users with role employee can only access the application from the office or its branches"

- IP checking? it is changeable
- How about if I follow private/public key? the disadvantage of that is that if I put the key in the cookie they can read it or may clear their cookies.
- Based on mac address ? it is changeable

Comment: Or you could simply program a `Filter` class, and override/implement `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filter) throws IOException, ServletException {`. Read more [here:](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Comment: do you know of an example or would you explain further I do not get you, if I use the filter then how to check them based on IP ?

Comment: You can recognize them based on Mac address of their computers.

Comment: @J888 Interesting but how ?

Comment: @TimNorman no idea just thought of

Comment: Both MAC and IP address (on local network) can be changed. Does not sound safe to depend on any information like that.

Comment: @Zapl so do you know of any better method ?

Comment: Nothing really practical. A hardware certificates that can be used to authenticate that it's the one it has to be. Burned into the hardware so user can't change it.

Comment: @J888, Mac address is only available if you are on the same LAN. You will not see their MAC address if there's a Router between you.

Comment: @TimNorman, is this a Windows environment?

Comment: @Vadim it is a website that part of it is going to be accessible by local users and another part is accessible globally

Comment: I have a whole new Idea. You could integrate with an access system, then when the employee tries to login your system, verify in the access system if they are in the company. You would have to spend money with hardware equipments to detect the physical location, but this is the price for security.

Answer (score 7):

You can't trust IPs and MAC addresses are even more useless, your only friend here is cryptography. Assuming your user will authenticate using his credentials you need to somehow authenticate the machine as well. This is done by placing a different certificate on each machine and having the client prove his "identity" to the server by using his certificate.

If your client-server communication is based on SSL, you can require client authentication - have a look at [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication), http://rap.ucar.edu/staff/paddy/cacerts/ or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/SSL_client.html.

If your communication is not based on SSL, or you wish to authenticate on the application level - you can still use the certificate. Load it from the truststore and prove your identity by proving you have access to the private key (usually the server sends a challenge, something random encrypted with the public key, you answer by decrypting it with the private key and sending it back. That way you prove you have the private key without having to show it).

If you do not wish to store certificates, you can just place a different encrypted file on each machine. The client will be able to decrypt it (using a hard coded key) and send something akin to a password to the server.

How do you protect these certificates? Read-only permissions for the users on the file...

Several notes -

1. You can't really EVER trust a client machine. A resourceful hostile user will break anything. The more resources you "enemies" have the more effort you need to put into your defence.
2. You didn't specify details regarding your environment. I'm sure there are system level solutions which I'm not aware of. For example - your server may connect to the Active Directory and monitor user logins on specific machines.
3. Sometimes the best solution may not come from the software level. For example, if your server uses a designated port for your communication. You could allow\block this traffic on your firewall\router\personal firewall - in places more adequate to resolve this issue than your server. If you have application control enforcement, you can allow the client itself to run on only specific machines.
4. You can also look for ways to create some unique PC fingerprint (motherboard Id, cpu id, SID in Active Directory, HDD id, MAC address...) - your server could then store a list of allowed fingerprints and your client will send the currently calculated fingerprint. This still comes back to - how well do you trust your clients?

Answer (score 3):

Restricting by IP only works if people are coming from places that have static IPs.  Anywhere like at home where you have dynamic it doesn't work.

If you can't use static and still want to restrict by IP you could use a service like http://dyn.com/dns/ to assign a FQDN to your IP.  Then you could do lookup by FQDN to see if it returns an IP that matches the one in the request.  This lookup could be cached so you're only doing every few hours.  The tricky part to this is that each location would have to setup of a dynamic DNS client.  Some routers now have this built in.

You can't get the MAC address through the HttpServlet class. And if could you'd get the MAC address from the device that is talking to your server which most likely would be something like a router, load balance, switch.  MAC address aren't not route'able.

Re: Keys, you can use x509 certs - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/x509.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not interested in any method which would solve the problem.

Comment: 'not interested in any'?  did you mean 'interested in any'?   if you did mean any let me know if you'd like me to expand on anything.

Comment: Sorry my type, I am not interested in IP or Mac address methods, as they are easily changeable. I read the documentation of x509 it is interesting but it seems its platform dependent, and also I am going to be charged for the authorization service right ?do you know of any other method ?

Comment: yes, it's possible for there to be cost deploying a PKI to use x509 certs.  People could also move/copy the client cert so it's really a good solution to control access by location.  

by IP is really the only I know of to restrict access by location.  it's just a bit painful if you have to deal with dynamic IPs.  in the past i solved this type of problem by requiring a static IP from users.

Comment: so whats  the final solution for this issue? using the certificate which is costly ? I dont get the first sentence of your comment "
It's possible for there to be cost deploying a PKI" ?

Comment: If you self sign your certs you can setup some servers for PKI.  If you need certs signed by a trusted CA it's going to cost you some money.  BUT, I don't think using certs will work.  As far as I know limited by IP is the only way to restrict by location.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The only way to restrict users in a certain place is the following:

- You must define Fixed IP's in the Office!
- Or, at least, a subnet mask for the office and it's branches.
- In your application, check the subnet mask from the request and compare it to fixed preconfigured office subnet mask.
- Thus, either you put those fixed IP's into webconf.xml or the subnet mask for the IPs;

In any event, the solution will always be connected to a network solution.

You could try something like this to check a fixed IP:

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter{ 

     public void destroy() {}  
     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {} 

     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain        filter) throws IOException, ServletException 
     {  
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;  
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;  

        IpAddressMatcher matcher = new IpAddressMatcher("192.168.1.0/24");

        try {
            if(!matcher.matches(req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"))){
               res.sendRedirect("AnotherPage.jsp");  
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            //Handle IT
        }
     }     

}
```

Also, you may need check the following, to catch every situation:

```
    request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Can they change their ip to something in accepted range of application?

Comment: does that mean IP is provided by their ISP and is not changeable?

Comment: @TimNorman I was thinking of vote systems which are IP based, so should not be changeable but using Mac address, you force them to use the same computer all the time.

Comment: If you want to restrict DEFINED IP's, you handle it manualy. Otherwise, you must think something else.

Comment: what do you mean by whitelist ? does that mean to keep the authorized ips in a file or database and check them all the time?

Comment: You could check a subnet mask, and define in the the office's router the specific mask, then check if IP fits in the subnet mask

Comment: @MatheusFreitas but even using SubNet at the end they have a single IP so its simple to change that to their own at home am I right ?

Comment: @TimNorman Mostly ISP works with dynamically generated IP for it's users, al least in my country

Answer (score 2):

I just want to address this part of your Question:

> I am trying to implement the IP method but it runs into following error.

```
  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.project.Default and
      com.project.Default$IpCheckService disagree on InnerClasses attribute
```

An `IncompatibleClassChangeError` means that there is a conflict between what the types were at compile time and what they are at runtime.  In this case, it seems to be that you have (had) a nested `IpCheckService` class that has changed from `static` to non-`static` (or *vice-versa!*), and somehow you've managed to load an old version of one of the classes.

This is a build or deployment problem.  If you can figure out what is going wrong here there is a good chance that your code will work.  (At least, you won't get *this* exception any more.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007212/how-to-restrict-users-with-specific-roles-to-access-the-application-from-a-ce), you can identify them based on their mac address.

This [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/parameters.html) is also helpful.

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App{

   public static void main(String[] args){

    InetAddress ip;
    try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

}
```

Comment: you can't get the MAC address from a client.  You get the MAC address from the device that is talking to your server which most likely would be something like a router, load balance, switch.

Comment: @denov I know but in this case he can set the mac address of where authorized users of his application are using it. Rest of world will be unable to access it. whats do you think?

Comment: lets start with the fact that MAC addresses are non routable.

Comment: yes, IP is the only way i know of to limit by location.  see comments below.

Answer (score 0):

To set up such kind of authorization rules, the first thing need to be defined is:

- What is the definition of "office or its branches" in terms of computer identification?
  Usually it is computers from some subnetwork as written in answers above - in that case the solution is obvious.
- Second possibility - some guy came to the office with his personal computer or laptop or touchpad, etc. If this is allowed by security policy, the only entity we can authenticate is user. We might still want to differ access from the office (as physical location, e.g. building)/from home. In that case I'd recommend to look at one-time-password generation devices that should be available to user **only** in the office.

Answer (score 0):

"Users with role employee can only access the application from the office or its branches"

Use a site-to site VPN. This effectively transforms the problem into an intranet login problem, which is trivial to solve.

By having a site-to-site VPN, you can be assured of the identity of the remote sites, since connection setup and authentication is generally performed by routers on site, the configuration of which users at the site do not need to know (or have on their computers, so cannot take away).

Once transformed into an intranet problem, just bind the application to an intranet address and secure it as you would any other intranet resource.