# how to do an online xml request in java to a url that require authentication

Tags: java, xml, ssl-certificate

I want to do an online xml request in java but the server responds with 401 error that means that there is an authentication that is need to access the server. I have the certfile.cer that i can use to do the authentication but i dont know how to load it in java.How can I achieve this in java? Here is part of my code.

```
StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
URL url = new URL("www.myurl.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
writer.write(xml);
writer.flush();
 String line;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
 answer.append(line);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication)

Comment: In addition to that SO question linked by @Jens, also check this link: http://vafer.org/blog/20061010073725/ (it contains a Java code example)

Comment: @nhylated how can convert the cert file to a keystore?

Comment: @MorganM Check the SO question linked by @Jens: `keytool -import -keystore ./client-truststore.jks -file myca.crt -alias myca`

Comment: @nhylated I have managed to generate the keystore here is my code that is now giving me null pointer exception.   HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory(new File("client-truststore.jks"), "mypass"));//here is where the null pointer error is
           
            
             OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());