# Send soap message with java

Tags: java, soap, https

I am experiencing a problem while trying to send a soap request on a https server. 
I seems that I am not sending any certificate but I don't know how to do that. I get an SSL handshake error. 
Here is my source code. Sorry for the mess .... :)

```
    public class Sign {

    static String myToken = "";
    static SOAPMessage signedRequest = null;
    static SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = null;

    static String url = "";
    static String fileToSend = "";
    static String receiptDir = "";
    static String jksKey = "";
    static String keyPwd = "";
    static String privKeyAlias = "";
    static TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            url = args[0];
            System.out.println(url);
            fileToSend = args[1];
            System.out.println(fileToSend);
            receiptDir = args[2];
            System.out.println(receiptDir);
            jksKey = args[3];
            System.out.println(jksKey);
            keyPwd = args[4];
            System.out.println(keyPwd);
            privKeyAlias = args[5];
            System.out.println(privKeyAlias);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Paramètres incorrects !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Timestamp to use
        SimpleDateFormat formater = null;
        Date aujourdhui = new Date();
        formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        myToken = formater.format(aujourdhui);
        // myToken = "20150112202835";


        ////////////////////////////
        // Constructing the message
        ////////////////////////////
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(soapEnvelope.getPrefix());
        soapEnvelope.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", "http://tempuri.org/");
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("elc",
                "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ZIRE.Match.Presentation.WebService");

        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
        soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");

        Name nameSecurity = soapEnvelope.createName("Security", "wsse",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement soapSecurity = soapHeader.addChildElement(nameSecurity);
        soapSecurity.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsu",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        Name nameBinSec = soapEnvelope.createName("BinarySecurityToken", "wsse",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement soapBinSec = soapSecurity.addChildElement(nameBinSec);
        soapBinSec.setAttribute("EncodingType",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
        soapBinSec.setAttribute("ValueType",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3");
        soapBinSec.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "X509-" + myToken);

        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapBody.addAttribute(
                soapEnvelope.createName("id", "wsu",
                        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"),
                "id-" + myToken);
        soapBody.setIdAttribute("wsu:id", true);


        ////////////////////////////
        // Adding the real content
        ////////////////////////////
//       The real payload new String(readAllBytes(get("test.txt")))
        String xmlValue = "<![CDATA[" + readFile(fileToSend,  StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "]]>";      
//      String xmlValue = "<![CDATA[" + new String(readAllBytes(get(fileToSend))) + "]]>";
//      System.out.println(xmlValue);

        QName sendMessage = new QName("tem:SendMessage");
        QName request = new QName("tem:request");
        QName xmldata = new QName("elc:XmlData");

        SOAPElement sendMessageNode = soapBody.addChildElement(sendMessage);
        SOAPElement requestNode = soapBody.addChildElement(request);
        SOAPElement xmldataNode = soapBody.addChildElement(xmldata);

        xmldataNode.addTextNode(xmlValue);
        requestNode.addChildElement(xmldataNode);
        sendMessageNode.addChildElement(requestNode);
        Source source = soapPart.getContent();


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Sending the request to the signing function
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Node root = ((DOMSource) source).getNode();     
        signedRequest = addSignature(root.getFirstChild().getOwnerDocument());


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SSL mode configuration
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            // Using null here initialises the TMF with the default trust store.
            tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

            // Get hold of the default trust manager
            X509TrustManager defaultTm = null;
            for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                    defaultTm = (X509TrustManager) tm;
                    break;
                }
            }

            FileInputStream myKeys = new FileInputStream("D:\\ZIRE\\MesCertificats\\myTrustStore");

            // Do the same with your trust store this time
            // Adapt how you load the keystore to your needs
            KeyStore myTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            myTrustStore.load(myKeys, "zire2016".toCharArray());

            myKeys.close();

            tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(myTrustStore);

            // Get hold of the default trust manager
            X509TrustManager myTm = null;
            for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                    myTm = (X509TrustManager) tm;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Wrap it in your own class.
            final X509TrustManager finalDefaultTm = defaultTm;
            final X509TrustManager finalMyTm = myTm;
            X509TrustManager customTm = new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    // If you're planning to use client-cert auth,
                    // merge results from "defaultTm" and "myTm".
                    return finalDefaultTm.getAcceptedIssuers();
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    try {
                        finalMyTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        // This will throw another CertificateException if this fails too.
                        finalDefaultTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    // If you're planning to use client-cert auth,
                    // do the same as checking the server.
                    finalDefaultTm.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                }
            };


            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { customTm }, null);

            // You don't have to set this as the default context,
            // it depends on the library you're using.
            SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);



            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Sending the request to the receiver
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();       
            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server     
//          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\ZIRE\\MesCertificats\\myTrustStore" );
//          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "zire2016");     
//          System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
//           SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(signedRequest, url);
//          doTrustToCertificates();
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = sendMessage(signedRequest, url);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Processing the response
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Cleaning of the response
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapResponse.writeTo(out);
        String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        int d = strMsg.indexOf("<s:Envelope");
        int f = strMsg.indexOf("</s:Envelope>") + 13;
        String strMsg2 = strMsg.substring(d, f);
        // System.out.println(strMsg2);
        // Writting of the response on the server
//      PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("D:\\ZIRE\\Result.xml");
//      fileToSend
//      String receiptFileName = (new File(fileToSend)).getParent() + "Receipt_" +  (new File(fileToSend)).getName();
//      System.out.println(receiptFileName);

        // Writing the response
        String receiptFileName = receiptDir + "Receipt_" +  (new File(fileToSend)).getName();
        System.out.println(receiptFileName);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( receiptFileName );
        printWriter.println(strMsg2);
        printWriter.close();
        soapConnection.close();

    }

    public static SOAPMessage addSignature(Document contenu)
            throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
            IOException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException, KeyException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, MarshalException,
            XMLSignatureException, TransformerException, InvalidKeySpecException, XMLSecurityException, SOAPException {

        // Chargement des clés
//      FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\ZIRE\\Step 1\\mock\\NewJKS.jks");
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(jksKey);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, null);

//      tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); // PKIX
//      tmf.init(keystore);

//       Enumeration<String> myEnum = keystore.aliases();
//      for (Enumeration<String> e = keystore.aliases(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
//          String newAlias = e.nextElement();
//          System.out.println(newAlias);
//          if (newAlias != "wsgbit" ) {
//              System.out.println(keystore.getCertificate(newAlias));
//          }   
//      }

        // Recup clé privée
//      String alias = "wsgbit";
        String alias = privKeyAlias;
//      Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPwd.toCharArray());
        KeyPair kp = null;
        Certificate cert = null;
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
            // Get certificate of public key
            cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            // Get public key
            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

            // Return a key pair
            kp = new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
        }

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = contenu;
//       dumpDocument(doc);


        // MAJ du champ wsse:BinarySecurityToken
        Element elt = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Node myBinSecElt = (Node) (elt.getElementsByTagName("wsse:BinarySecurityToken")).item(0);
        myBinSecElt.setTextContent(Utf8.decode(Base64.encode(cert.getEncoded())));

        // Debut
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();

        Node mySecElt = (Node) (elt.getElementsByTagName("wsse:Security")).item(0);
        org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature xmlSignature = new org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature(
                doc, "", org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1,
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
        Element eltSign = xmlSignature.getElement();
        eltSign.setAttribute("Id", "SIG-" + myToken);
        mySecElt.appendChild(eltSign);

        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
        transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
        xmlSignature.addDocument("#id-" + myToken, transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);

        SOAPElement myCanonElt = (SOAPElement) (elt.getElementsByTagName("ds:CanonicalizationMethod")).item(0);
        InclusiveNamespaces inclusiveNamespaces = new InclusiveNamespaces(doc, "elc soapenv tem");
        myCanonElt.appendChild(inclusiveNamespaces.getElement());

        SOAPElement mySoapTransform = (SOAPElement) (elt.getElementsByTagName("ds:Transform")).item(0);
        InclusiveNamespaces inclusiveNamespaces2 = new InclusiveNamespaces(doc, "elc tem");
        mySoapTransform.appendChild(inclusiveNamespaces2.getElement());

        // Ajustements
        // SOAPElement myCanonElt = (SOAPElement)
        // (elt.getElementsByTagName("ds:CanonicalizationMethod")).item(0);
        // myCanonElt.setAttribute("Algorithm",
        // "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
        // Name nameInclusiveNamespaces =
        // soapEnvelope.createName("InclusiveNamespaces", "ec",
        // "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
        // SOAPElement soapInclusiveNamespaces =
        // myCanonElt.addChildElement(nameInclusiveNamespaces);
        // soapInclusiveNamespaces.setAttribute("PrefixList", "elc soapenv
        // tem");
        //
        // SOAPElement mySoapTransform = (SOAPElement)
        // (elt.getElementsByTagName("ds:Transform")).item(0);
        // Name nameInclusiveNamespaces2 =
        // soapEnvelope.createName("InclusiveNamespaces", "ec",
        // "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");
        // SOAPElement soapInclusiveNamespaces2 =
        // mySoapTransform.addChildElement(nameInclusiveNamespaces2);
        // soapInclusiveNamespaces2.setAttribute("PrefixList", "elc tem");
        //
        Name nameKeyInfo = soapEnvelope.createName("KeyInfo", "ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        SOAPElement mySoapSign = (SOAPElement) (elt.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature")).item(0);
        SOAPElement soapKeyInfo = mySoapSign.addChildElement(nameKeyInfo);
        soapKeyInfo.setAttribute("Id", "KI-" + myToken);

        Name nameSecToken = soapEnvelope.createName("SecurityTokenReference", "wsse",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement soapSecToken = soapKeyInfo.addChildElement(nameSecToken);
        soapSecToken.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "STR-" + myToken);

        Name nameRef = soapEnvelope.createName("Reference", "wsse",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement soapNameRef = soapSecToken.addChildElement(nameRef);
        soapNameRef.setAttribute("URI", "#X509-" + myToken);
        soapNameRef.setAttribute("ValueType",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3");

        xmlSignature.sign(key);
//      xmlSignature.sign(key);
//      dumpDocument(doc);

        // String xml = new XMLOutputter().outputString(doc);

        // Ecriture du String represantant la requete signée
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
//      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
//      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
//      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
//      String xml = sw.toString(); System.out.println(">>>" + xml + "<<<");

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));// new
                                                                                                    // InputStream(xml);
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        return messageFactory.createMessage(null, inputStream);

        // Ecriture dans un fichier
        // Transformer transformer =
        // TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        // Result output = new StreamResult(new
        // FileOutputStream("D:\\ZIRE\\mySignedFile2.xml"));
        // Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
        // transformer.transform(input, output);

    }

    public static String convertToString(Document document) throws TransformerException {

        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(sw);
        // create an instance of TransformerFactory
        TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        trans.transform(domSource, result);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    private static void dumpDocument(Node root) throws TransformerException {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
//      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(root), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

    private static Element getFirstChildElement(Node node) {
        Node child = node.getFirstChild();
        while ((child != null) && (child.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
            child = child.getNextSibling();
        }
        return (Element) child;
    }

    public static Element getNextSiblingElement(Node node) {
        Node sibling = node.getNextSibling();
        while ((sibling != null) && (sibling.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
            sibling = sibling.getNextSibling();
        }
        return (Element) sibling;
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    static public SOAPMessage sendMessage(SOAPMessage message, String endPoint) throws SOAPException, IOException {
        SOAPMessage result = null;
        if (endPoint != null && message != null) {
            URL url;
            SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = scf.createConnection(); //point-to-point connection
                url = new URL(endPoint);
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                con.connect();
                result = connection.call(message, url);
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (SOAPException soape) {
                        System.out.print("Can't close SOAPConnection:" + soape);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public void doTrustToCertificates() throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return;
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                    System.out.println("Warning: URL host '" + urlHostName + "' is different to SSLSession host '" + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    }
}
```

Wireshark has shown me I am not sending my certificate though I am using JVM params like -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=... 
    But I am wondering how can the JVM know where is my certificate as I can have many certificates in a jks file ???

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a https-site you do not have to send a cert by default. the server has to send and your client will eval it (by uri, expiry-date, cert-chain, ...). if the cert is valid your http-client should accept it by default.

in other cases you can import the cert of the server to your local keystore (jks) and the client will accept it, cause you never would import "untrusted" certs to your local keystore.

or you implement a code like "who cares the cert? just do it!" (link: [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)).
**but this is not supposed to be used in public/prod environment (like internet)**

Comment: In fact in the case I am, the server ask for my certificate during the SSL handshake and I have to provide it for him to continue communicating with me. When I am using soapUI everything works fine and I can see in wireshark that soapUI has thansmitted my certificate to the sever.