# Java GET call with certificate for authentication

Tags: java

I have the C# code below which works, I want to write the same thing in java.

My searches on Stack Overflow were unsuccessful, all of the questions have a `.pem` file in use.

I realize that it must be pretty straightforward, but I'm stuck with this since a week!

```
string serviceURL = "https://someurl";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
request.Method = "GET";
string path = @"C:\mycert.cer";
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(path);

Logger.Error(path);

request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);

HttpWebResponse WebResp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
string responseText;
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
using (reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
{
    responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Which part of the functionality you want in java?

Comment: The whole of the above code in java

Comment: Possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: No sorry, that answer does not talk about sending certificate from client to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication)