# Mqtt client ssl example in java

Tags: java, facebook, ssl, certificate, mqtt

I am tired to connect facebook MQTT server ( edge-mqtt.facebook.com:443 ) with ssl , I'm using [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) for MQTT connection .

```
private final String DEFAULT_HOST = "edge-mqtt.facebook.com";
private final int DEFAULT_PORT = 443;

public void connect(String protogle) throws Exception {

this.broker =  protogle + "://"+ DEFAULT_HOST + ":" + DEFAULT_PORT;
this.mqttClient = new MqttClient(broker,getMqttClientId() ,new MemoryPersistence() );

MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval( MQTT_KEEPALIVE);
connOpts.setUserName( getMqttUsername() );
connOpts.setPassword( getMqttPassword().toCharArray() );
connOpts.setMqttVersion( 3 );
//connOpts.setSocketFactory(getSocketFactory (caCrtFile,crtFile,keyFile,password) );
Logger.w("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
Logger.w("isConnected:"+mqttClient.isConnected());
try {
    IMqttToken cn = mqttClient.connectWithResult(connOpts);
    Logger.w("connected");
}catch (MqttException me){
    System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
    System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
    System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
    System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
    System.out.println("excep "+me);
    return;
}



this.mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable me) {
        Logger.w("Connection lost");
        System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
        System.out.println("excep "+me);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        Logger.w("message Arrived");
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        Logger.w("deliverd--------");
        try {
            MqttDeliveryToken token  = (MqttDeliveryToken) iMqttDeliveryToken;
            String h = token.getMessage().toString();
            Logger.w("deliverd message :"+h);
        } catch (MqttException me) {
            System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
            System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
            System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
            System.out.println("excep "+me);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory (final String caCrtFile, final String crtFile, final String keyFile,
                                          final String password) throws Exception
{
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // load CA certificate
    PEMReader reader = new PEMReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(caCrtFile)))));
    X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)reader.readObject();
    reader.close();

    // load client certificate
    reader = new PEMReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(crtFile)))));
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)reader.readObject();
    reader.close();

    // load client private key
    reader = new PEMReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFile)))),
            new PasswordFinder() {
                @Override
                public char[] getPassword() {
                    return password.toCharArray();
                }
            }
    );
    KeyPair key = (KeyPair)reader.readObject();
    reader.close();

    // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
    KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    caKs.load(null, null);
    caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(caKs);

    // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate us
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, null);
    ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
    ks.setKeyEntry("private-key", key.getPrivate(), password.toCharArray(), new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{cert});
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

    // finally, create SSL socket factory
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
}
```

I'm searching for how to create caCrtFile , crtFile and keyFile and got many answers . i confused and now i don't know which answer is true . for example i got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication) . but i can't implement that and all times i got SSL error . any one can give me example to creating these files for edge-mqtt.facebook.com:443 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do only need a `crtFile` and `keyFile` if you are trying to do SSL mutual authentication. If this is the case then Facebook would issue you with the required files.

The `caCrtFile` is a certificate chain to verify the certificate supplied by the Facebook broker when you connect to it. The certificate for edge-mqtt.facebook.com issued by DigiCert Inc so the required CA cert should already be included in the Java Runtime.

All this means you should be able to use the default SSLSocketFactory witoout having to add your own truststore or keystore.

EDIT:

So delete all of the `getSocketFactory()` method and replace it with `SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();`

Comment: thats good . can you give me example to do it ? please update the answer with example ?

Comment: Edited to add what to change

Comment: this is not work for me . do you know how can i create these files ?

Comment: You can't create them, Facebook would have to do it for you (if they support mutual SSL authentication)

Comment: but this api implement this ssl and it's worked ! https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API . please help me . i'm very tired