# Message Signing in SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, soap, glassfish, cxf, wss4j

I am developing a java client to connect to a web service which uses SOAP. In Intellij

```
TOOLS>GENERATE JAVA CODE FROM WSDL
```

has generated the stubs and I have connected to the insecure endpoint.

I now need to sign and encrypt the message body with a public certificate. I have read about Axis, CXF, WSS4J and Glassfish but I am still unclear which of these packages I would use?

Comment: Using a certificate in a soap request is a little tricky,  See this link for some pointers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication

Comment: @MikeMurphy thanks - that SO refers to SSL security rather than SOAP message body encryption/signing.

Comment: SSL uses a certificate to encrypt the complete message content not just the body.  This link explains how it works.  http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10241.  Are you thinking of a "do it yourself" solution to encrypt the message body only?