# Problems with Google Api query in Clojure

Tags: clojure, google-api, clj-http

When I am executing the following query

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as http])

(http/post "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo" 
           {:query-params {:access_token "token"}})
```

> *SunCertPathBuilderException unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build
>   (SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)*

This error also sometimes appears when executing the code

> *ExceptionInfo clj-http: status 404  slingshot.support/stack-trace (support.clj:201)*

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to review these two sections:

- Enable logging at the debug level, so you can get a better idea of why it's failing: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#logging
- I think the issue is related to missing configuration for calls to an HTTPS address. Try changing the call as shown here: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#keystores-trust-stores . Here is an example answer that shows how to set SSL certs in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710543/483566

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Denis for the prompt response! I have reviewed the links, however what I found is to change the JDK 8 to JDK 7. But I would like to know why this situation occurs.