# How to view the client certificate in Mojolicious::Plugin::SslAuth plugin?

Tags: perl, ssl, https, mojolicious

I have set up a [Mojolicious::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite) server with SSL support using Hypnotoad. I am using [Mojolicious::Plugin::SslAuth](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious-Plugin-SslAuth/README.pod) for authenticating the client certificate. When I call `dump_peer_certificate()` I get

```
[Tue Feb 12 07:26:32 2019] [debug] peer: Subject Name: undefined Issuer  Name: undefined
```

but I expected valid certificate information. Can you help me to understand this message?

Here is SSL handler code:

```perl
sub register {
    my ($plugin, $app) = @_;

    $app->helper(
        ssl_auth => sub {
            my $self     = shift;
            my $callback = shift;

            my $id     = $self->tx->connection;
            my $handle = Mojo::IOLoop->stream($id)->handle;

            # dump_peer_certificate returns-
            #     Subject Name: undefined
            #     Issuer  Name: undefined 
            $app->log->debug("peer: " . $handle->dump_peer_certificate());

            # Not SSL connection
            return if ref $handle ne 'IO::Socket::SSL';

            return $callback->($handle);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: There is probably no client certificate, ie. `$handle->peer_certificate()` will not return anything. I think it is extremely rare to enable certificates in SSL clients, e.g. if you require your server to only accept clients that provide a valid certificate.

Comment: I.e. calling `dump_peer_certificate()` only makes sense on the *client* side. It will of course print the information of the server certificate.

Comment: Quoting from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710543/8866606): "(1) **Client certificate authentication can only be enforced by the server.**
(2) (Important!) When the server requests a client certificate (as part of the TLS handshake), it will also provide a list of trusted CA's as part of the certificate request. When the client certificate you wish to present for authentication is *not* signed by one of these CA's, it won't be presented at all" - have you set up your SSL server to request client certificate authentication?

Comment: @StefanBecker I have added the SSL certificate in my browser and SoapUI. Therefore, I presume it should be sending the certificate in the request. I didn't find relevant info in Mojo::Lite docs to enable client certificate authentication.

Comment: My statements are not specific to Mojo::Lite, i.e. they apply to any SSL/TLS server/client setup. I.e. without additional setup the SSL server won't request and the SSL client won't authenticate with a certificate. This is **different** from the other direction, i.e. a server always needs to authenticate with a certificate to the client.

Comment: Did you configure hypnotoads listen attribute with a CA certificate file  to verify the client certificate?

Comment: Thank you @clamp! I had not set `?ca=...` in the hypnotoad listen config