# Calling RestAPI with SSL certificate in java

Tags: java

I need to call a restapi which requires SSL certificate which i have installed on WebSphere. Now when i hit the API it gives me an error of 401 not authenticated. Using SSL Certificate i am able to call using PostMan By Attaching Client Certificate and attaching passphrase and private key reference

SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

```
            TrustManager[ ] trustcertmgr = getCerticateTrustManager();
            sslctx.init(null,                // key manager
                         trustcertmgr,           // trust manager
                         new SecureRandom()); // random number generator

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslctx.getSocketFactory());

            url = new URL(clienturl);



            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession sess)
            {

                return false;
            }});
            System.err.println("Connection Created with URL:" + clienturl);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication)