# Using .p12 file to execute request to rest server

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth2resttemplate

I'm trying to execute requests to a server which provided me with a .p12 file in order to make secure connection with rest services, I'm doing the following in order to set the HttpClient with the key:

```
SSLContext sslContext =SSLContextBuilder
                .create().loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore/file.p12"), "secret".toCharArray(), "secret".toCharArray())
                .build();

    return HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager())
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig())
            .build();
```

When I execute the request with **OAuth2RestOperations** I got:

```
401 , Non existing certificate or invalid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had a similar requirement. Here is the code I used:

```
    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    try {
        clientStore.load(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore/file.p12"), "secret".toCharArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception
    }

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(clientStore, "secret".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    return builder.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```

Comment: Did you configure something in your computer? I have tested same code and It does not work, I'm checking the CN information included in the request, and I can't see the information of the key. It seems like the key is not taken locally

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a duplicate question.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513368/42962) for this question [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1666052/42962).

Answer (score 0):

In all [examples](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder/loadKeyMaterial) you need to call [loadKeyMaterial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadKeyMaterial(java.security.KeyStore,%20char[])) method with `KeyStore`

> ```
>  public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(KeyStore keystore,
> ```

Load the keyStore using file path, for example:

> ```
> keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
> FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(certPath));
> keyStore.load(inputStream, certPassword.toCharArray());
> ```