# How to import .cer / .p12 into mobile application

Tags: java, http, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have a SOAP request to make through HTTPS which requires a self-signed certificate. I have it in the format of .p12 or .cer

Do I do

1. Certificate pinning in my source code (using
   https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http)
2. Configure own SSL Context ([Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication?rq=1))
3. Sign the APK file with the certificate

I am not sure the difference 1 and 2 achieves. Anybody can help explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-client-cert-authentication

Usually when accessing the server through browser, there will be a popup asking for the certificate.

This plugin achieves that and when you run your request, the popup will be triggered. 
But user will have to install the cert on their mobile phones.

This method will not require any additional coding on your part.