# Which SSL certificate will be selected if client has multiple certificates in key store

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, ssl-client-authentication

Could you please help me on following two questions?

I have a FIX engine that connects to FIX servers. There is a FIX server that requires client to authenticate itself during SSL handshake. It also provides a SSL certificate that I need to use during SSL handshake as client side certificate.

**Question#1:** Can I store multiple certificates (private keys) in a keystore that I will load later in my FIX engine?

**Question#2:** If answer to #1 is yes, then how would the SSL context select a client certificate during SSL handshake when it establishes a SSL connection with the server?

Note- I am thinking of these questions because in future there may be another Servers that also have similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Question#1: Can I store multiple certificates (private keys) in a keystore that I will load later in my FIX engine?

As far as Java is concerned, you definitely can have multiple privateKey entries, each containing a privatekey plus certificate or (usually) chain, in one keystore file or other storage object. (Note that if you use PKCS12 *to interchange with other software* that other software may not support multiple entries in one PKCS12. If you use PKCS12 only for better security in Java, or to silence the warnings in j9+, this is not a concern.)

I don't know what FIX engine you are using, or how it handles its key-and-cert info for TLS-formerly-SSL (or indeed how it handles TLS at all). If it simply loads a keystore file (or stream) as a KeyStore object, the the Java capability above applies. If it does something else, what it can do depends on that something else.

> Question#2: If answer to #1 is yes, then how would the SSL context select a client certificate during SSL handshake when it establishes a SSL connection with the server?

In the TLS protocol, when a server requests that the client use a certificate, it specifies algorithm constraints (the leaf key algorithms through 1.2 and/or the chain signature algorithms in 1.2 and 1.3) and may specify a list of desired Certificate Authorities (CAs) (which may have issued any cert in the chain).

If your client (FIX engine) uses the Java-standard implementation of TLS (JSSE) with its standard (and default) 'SunX509' KeyManager, that will choose from the keystore an entry satisfying the above constraints from the server; if you select or configure the 'NewSunX509' or 'PKIX' KeyManager, it also checks any algorithm constraints defined for your JVM (for example Oracle JVMs since about 2017 prohibit certs using MD5- or SHA1-based signatures, or RSA keys less than 1024 bits), and gives preference to entries where the cert is not expired and does not have inappropriate KeyUsage or ExtendedKeyUsage extensions. Among multiple acceptable or preferred entries the selection is arbitrary -- however the keystore implementation enumerated them. Most servers support all standard (maybe and non-obsolete) algorithms and usually cannot be distinguished by that. If a server accepts certs from 'public' CAs like Digicert, GoDaddy, LetsEncrypt those also are not likely distinct, but if it uses a CA (or perhaps a few) specific to that server or its operator, such CA name(s) will often be unique and thus the key-and-cert will be selected only for that server.

If your client uses a custom KeyManager -- either explicitly in your application or via middleware (for example Apache HttpClient) -- it can do something different. It can even choose to use a key-and-cert the server will reject, although that would normally not be considered useful.

If your client uses a different TLS implementation, that could use the standard KeyManager structure, probably with the options above, or could do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

if you use spring framework you can specify alias of certificate that you prefer to select by adding

`-Dserver.ssl.key-alias=your_preffered_alias`

Answer (score -1):

1. You said that you have a FIX engine that connects to FIX server, then asked if private keys can be stored in a keystore for your FIX engine. This leads me to believe that the FIX engine is in a client application. You should NOT store private keys publicly in a keystore. Instead, you should be providing the client with a truststore, which just contains the certificate.
2. I don't have an answer for this, but this post might be helpful; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710543/4417924

Comment: Regarding #1, yes FIX engine (my side application) is the client that tries to connect to FIX Server (other side application). This connection is TCP/IP connection over SSL. The FIX Server requires client side authentication. So, my FIX engine needs to present client side certificate during SSL handshake. So, I need to store the certificate in java key store that I load for my application. The FIX Server provides client cert and private key. The server expects the same cert to be presented by client during SSL handshake. I am supporting this requirement loading a keystore.