# Java Webservices SOAP with client auth and p12 certificate

Tags: java, web-services, pkcs#12

I need to call a webservice from a Java stand-alone application. The webservice requires client-auth access and it has a https:// url.

The user of the application should provide a p12 certificate and a pin code in order to gain access to the webservice.

The customer provided me an example certificate to test the webservice, but I actually have no idea how to implement it.

In the real application the certificate is stored in a smartcard (pkcs#11).

Where should I have to see to find a howto or some examples? Thanks...

Comment: you can look over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940404/mirth-calling-an-ssl-soap-web-service-with-a-client-certificate

Comment: Will your client use JAX-WS?  If so, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729188/jaxws-client-to-invoke-jaxws-webservice-using-x509-server-authentication